# Bundle id for iOS in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How can I find bundle id and package name for iOS in a Xamarin forms app? I'm able to find the package name of Android in Android manifest but no clue about iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Xamarin.Essentials: App Information you can get that info and displayed inside your app

```
// Application Name
var appName = AppInfo.Name;

// Package Name/Application Identifier (com.microsoft.testapp)
var packageName = AppInfo.PackageName;

// Application Version (1.0.0)
var version = AppInfo.VersionString;

// Application Build Number (1)
var build = AppInfo.BuildString;
```

For further info take a look at this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/app-information?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android

Answer (score 17):

Bundle identifier is defined within a `Info.plist` under iOS project root.
 This file is like `AndroidManifest.xml` on Android.

Comment: Thanks @Evz for ur answer

Comment: I followed the same process

Answer (score 8):

Look inside your `info.plist` file. You'll see a key called `CFBundleIdentifier` and it's in there.

Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>My App Name</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>MyBundleName</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.example.myappidentifier</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>10.0</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>47</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Other interesting keys are `CFBundleShortVersionString` which have your app's version number (the marketing version number such as 1.0, 1.1.0 etc), and `CFBundleVersion` which include your build number (1, 2, 3, etc).

Also note: .plist files are an XML format. You'll notice the `<dict>` line that starts off a dictionary section. Inside that you'll see a series of `<key>*</key>` lines, each followed by a value for that key, which could be a simple type like a string, or a more complex type like an array or even another dictionary etc. When reading/editing a .plist file, the value for each key is right below the key. In this example, the `CFBundleIdentifier` has a value of `com.example.myappidentifier`.

If you need to read your bundle id in code, you can add this property to a class in your Xamarin.Forms iOS project:

```
public String BundleId => NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleIdentifier;
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave Wood and  for your answer.